# How to indicatorize a systray-only app?

Tags: python, indicator, programming, system-tray

I just realized that under 13.04 it isn't possible any more to add applications which are using the systray to a whitelist. I found the suggestion of downloading a patched version of Unity but I'd rather make one app I like (see [bug report for blueproximity)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blueproximity/+bug/919109) use app-indicator instead.

I saw several python apps exist for application indicator, for instance [ClassicMenu Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/46811/117103) . So I want to try to adapt the program.

What I need now is a pointer where/how to start, maybe a few hints. (No experience with python but plenty with several other languages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [very short explanation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/) and code samples for Python and some other  languages at the Ubuntu app developers resources. For blueproximity the PyGTK example should fit.

You need some basic understanding of the [GTK signal system](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TheoryOfSignalsAndCallbacks.html)